# How do I disable autocomplete using javascript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, autocomplete

I've always searching how to disable autocomplete but I haven't found exact answers.

It is usually a problem of chrome browsers that setting autocomplete="off" into the html isn't working.

How do I disable autocomplete using javascript or JQuery?

Comment: Is the problem that autocomplete="off" is being ignored in Chrome?

Comment: Are you setting `autocomplete="off"` on an `<input>` element or on the `<form>`?

Comment: You can make Chrome listen by using this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/29582380/4462191

Answer (score 2):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        try {
            $("input[type='text']").each(function(){
                           $(this).attr("autocomplete","off");
                        });
        }
        catch (e)
        { }
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this workaround.

```
<input type="text" name="username" value=" " onclick="if(this.value == ' ') this.value=''" >
```

Click [here](http://zaverokris.blogspot.com/2014/09/disable-browsers-autocomplete-on-html.html) for more info about this.